# В C# Winforms MDI menustrip активной дочерней формы переходит на меню формы parent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu

Столкнулся с очень интересной ошибкой `MDI` форм. **Меню дочерней формы переноситься на родительскую `MenuStrip`**. Не можете ли подсказать, в чем может крыться проблема с таким передставлением пунктов меню(`MenuStrip`) на родительской форме? Так же, я пытался использовать `ContexMenuStrip`. Оно вообще не работает. Заранее благодарю. Ниже иллюстрация, как это выглядит с объектом `MenuStrip`. Проект новый, я ничего не менял.

**Зачем мне это нужно?**
Мне нужно создать какой-то объект - кнопку или пункт меню(*это то, до чего я догадался*), клацая на которую будет вызываться событие `Paint`(через `Invalidate()`). Если у вас есть мысли так же по этому поводу, буду очень благодарен.

Иллюстрация ошибки:
[image: Илюстрация ошибки]

Конструктор дочерней формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Конструктор родительской формы:

[image: Конструктор родительской формы]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно есть такая проблема (элементы меню дочернего окна по умолчанию перелетают в родителя). Однако это решаемо, если у меню выставить свойство `AllowMerge=false`

Чтобы контекстное меню показывалось, нужно у формы выставить свойство `ContextMenuStrip`. Можно у родителя сделать свое контекстное меню, у дочернего окна свое.

[Пример](https://github.com/miptleha/cs-mdi), как это все реализовано

Comment: Благодарю!) Оказалось, ответ так лаконичен!)